Unknown error while making a remote service call: Remote host terminated the handshake
I have updated the version of firebase-admin (Java SDK) to 9.3.0
When I try to send a batch (FirebaseMessaging.sendEach), I get the following error:
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Unknown error while making a remote service call: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException.withMessagingErrorCode(FirebaseMessagingException.java:51)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl$MessagingErrorHandler.createException(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:293)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl$MessagingErrorHandler.createException(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:282)
    at com.google.firebase.internal.AbstractHttpErrorHandler.handleIOException(AbstractHttpErrorHandler.java:63)
    at com.google.firebase.internal.ErrorHandlingHttpClient.send(ErrorHandlingHttpClient.java:110)
    at com.google.firebase.internal.ErrorHandlingHttpClient.sendAndParse(ErrorHandlingHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.sendSingleRequest(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:127)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.send(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:113)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$3.execute(FirebaseMessaging.java:248)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$3.execute(FirebaseMessaging.java:244)
    at com.google.firebase.internal.CallableOperation.call(CallableOperation.java:36)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:131)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:76)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1714)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1513)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1420)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1433)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1404)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:220)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
    at com.google.firebase.internal.ErrorHandlingHttpClient.send(ErrorHandlingHttpClient.java:96)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:483)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1505)
    ... 24 common frames omitted

There were no changes other than the version update. Why can this exception be thrown?
Update firebase-admin-java version to 9.3.0

@ReBI You have to whitelist your IP to unblock the firebase google URL to get succeeded
